# Bivariate generating function on the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $\sum_{m,n}^{\infty}p(x,y)=1$ where $p(x,y)$ is the stationary distribution of some two dimensional random walk and let its bivariate generating function be defined as:

$P(x,y)= \sum_{m}^{\infty}\sum_{n}^{\infty}p(x,y)x^{m}y^{n}$.

Can someone please show why $P(x,y)$ is analytic in the open domain

$\{{{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^{2}: |x|<1, |y|<1}}\}$

and continuous in the closed domain

$\{{{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^{2}: |x|\le 1, |y|\le 1}}\}$.